# How to see a 2-group as a 2-category with only one object?

Tags: category-theory, definition, higher-category-theory

We'll take the following definition of a 2-group:

> A 2-group $\mathsf{G}$ is a category internal to $\mathsf{Grp}$

Namely, it is a group $\mathsf{G_0}$ of objects, a group $\mathsf{G_1}$ of morphisms, together with maps:

$s,t:\mathsf{G_1}\rightarrow \mathsf{G_0}$ (source and target map)

$id:\mathsf{G_0}\rightarrow \mathsf{G_1}$ (the identity map)

$\circ: \mathsf{G_1}\times_{(s,t)}\mathsf{G_1}\rightarrow \mathsf{G_1}$ (composition map between composable morphisms)

such that the usual diagrams defining a category commute.

One way I see to view a 2-group as a 2-category is to say that a 2-group defined as previously is a monoidal category with the group composition as the tensor product. The delooping category $B\mathsf{G}$ is thus the manner to view a 2-group as a 2-category, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at what a 2-groupoid should be, then look at a 2-groupoid having just one object. Call the set of objects, $X_0$, take $X_1$, the set of 1-arrows (check this should be a groupoid), then $X_2$ as set of 2-arrows. Write down the axioms you expect, then specialise to look at the structure at a single object. You get a 2-group.  (Now reverse engineer the 2-groupoid from the 2-group.)

What you say about a 2-group as a (strict) monoidal category is also correct.

Comment: The following may be useful: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0212065

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the definition you gave is not the most suitable to catch the 2-categorical nature of 2-groups: you are probably interested in [this pdf](https://tetrapharmakon.github.io/stuff/repbeamer.pdf).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Fosco: your address has changed since you posted this reply. It would help if you updated it.

Comment: sorry I should have said that the link in your comment is dead.

Comment: I'll update the link asap! At the moment I'm in the middle of the Mediterranean sea relying on my phone's wifi only :)

Comment: Thanks for replying, enjoy the sea, Tim

Comment: @fosco: Would it be possible for you to update the link?

Comment: Sure; just fyi I haven't been trapped between the Aegean and the Mediterranean for 4 years... ;-)

Comment: https://tetrapharmakon.github.io/stuff/repbeamer.pdf there you have it